# JetDrive 725 - SHould I use TRIM enabler?

Tags: macos, security, ssd

I just installed a [JetDrive 725](http://nl.transcend-info.com/apple/jetdrive/)  and it is really nice!

As I am using Yosemite, TRIM can not be enabled that easily, and the [TRIM Enabler](https://www.cindori.org/software/trimenabler/) is needed. Now there is a certain risk when using it, as [kext-signing needs to be disabled](https://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/).

Now my question: is it worth enabling TRIM? Is it be really that beneficial? Any experiences with it?

Comment: To Trim or not to Trim, that is the question. Well, Apple thinks it is so important that they banned all non Apple products and you can only use theirs (or die without it). Is there a technical reason for that? probably not since Trim is Trim.

Comment: I don't understand your last statement - what do you mean by "Trim is Trim"? But I don't think that they specifically banned Trim for non-apple products, but that this is a side effect of the kext signing - and they don't see it as their concern (which it actually isn't - as it works with their hardware).

Comment: In case anyone arrives at this question and doesn't investigate further, it should be mentioned that [this linked question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164617/how-to-keep-an-ssd-in-shape-on-yosemite) provides a better answer as to how to avoid the issues with TRIM Enabler: As of 10.10.4 Apple provides the `trimforce` command, which works with 3rd Party drives too.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a 960GB JetDrive 720 since September 2014 and have been running Yosemite since release. I found that enabling trim on Yosemite caused instabilities, and the system would lock up very regularly. I was in regular contact with Transcend about this for a while. I like to think that the removal of trim from the JetDrive toolbox on Yosemite was down to my insistence, but we will never know for sure!

Turning of trim has solved all my problems. I did that in January 2015, and have not had any issues since. I work with a lot of virtual machines and this can be quite I/O intensive and I have seen no downsides of not enabling trim. I do boot into the recovery console about once a month to run Disk Utility to verify disk but I've not had any problems so this seems overcautious on my part.

### OS X 10.10.4 and later

Apple has included a command line tool that enables trim. If you're running 10.10.4 or later, be sure to save all open documents as the following commands will result in a system restart.

1. Launch Terminal
2. Type `sudo trimforce enable`. There will be some scary warnings about data loss, but this is standard CYA legalese. You will be prompted about whether you are sure ***twice***.
3. This will reboot your system. After the reboot, TRIM is now enabled.

Comment: Did you have instability with Apple's TRIM implementation and 'trimforce' ? Or using JetDrive's TRIM enabler ?

Comment: Apple's trimforce TRIM implementation has been rock solid for the past 10 months. On the other hand, the JetDrive toolbox TRIM implementation was clearly buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Never had a JetDrive, but I wouldn't use cindori's enabler, I'd use Jet's own -

There's no data on whether they do it the same way as cindori

> **Take control with JetDrive Toolbox.**
>
> Exclusively developed by Transcend for JetDrive SSDs, JetDrive Toolbox monitoring software leverages S.M.A.R.T. technology to analyze its health status. Additionally, it can enable TRIM support for your JetDrive in OS X®, maintaining optimum write speeds and maximizing the lifetime of your SSD.

http://www.transcend-info.com/Support/Software-181/

…later...Actually, the more I read, the less certain I am that their TRIM function will work on Yosemite.

Cindori's works for me on an 840 EVO, with the caveat of the kext signing disabled  - but frankly I have no clue what it's actually doing & if it helps in any real way.

Comment: I Downloaded the JetDrive toolbox, but the TRIM option is disabled under Yosemite - and the only one I found which is working is the TRIM Enabler from cindori. So you are using it because to be on the safe side?

Comment: tbh, I used it under Mavericks - didn't for a while under Yosemite; re-enabled it recently. I really can't tell if it's doing anything… it's too subtle for me - maybe I'll find out in 2 years when the drive wears out early ;)

Comment: Thanks - unless others opt for it, I will likely leave it at the moment without.

Comment: OK - I found Chameleon SSD Optimizer at http://chameleon.alessandroboschini.com/faq.php and it is doing the same as the TrimEnabler, only that it is free. I enabled Trim (confirmed in System Report) and so far no problems. Impression: it is faster.