# APPLE SSD SM0512F Media Equivalent

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, mac-pro

My `Mac Pro` (Late 2013) uses an `APPLE SSD SM0512F Media SSD`; I'd like to buy an equivalent `SSD` to use externally for cloning, backups, etc.

I noticed on the [PassMark website](http://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/hdd.php?hdd=APPLE%20SSD%20SM0512F) it shows performance information in comparison with some other `SSDs`, however, it doesn't show what `SSDs` are ranked directly above or below it, so I have no idea what it's closest competitors might be.

It doesn't appear Apple sells the `SM0512F` — what (if any) would be equivalent?

Comment: Be aware that Yosemite does not like the non Apple SSD's.

Comment: It might not like it, but they work without problems. Only TRIM is not working. I bought a Transcend JetDrive 725 SSD and it works really nice.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Rainer: Thanks for the recommendation; do all non-Apple SSDs have that issue with TRIM not working, and what (if any) resolution is there to it?

Comment: @Rainer correct, so how are you doing without the trim? The SSD wont last very long!

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Yes, I am doing it without TRIM. And there are quite a few who are doing it without TRIM. Could you please elaborate on your statement?

Comment: @I'L'I Yes. Apple is using kext signing and so no TRIM can be enabled for non-apple SSD, except of when using Trim Enabler at https://www.cindori.org/software/trimenabler/ See some other comments in this thread http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176821/jetdrive-725-should-i-use-trim-enabler where I asked a similar question. See also https://www.cindori.org/documentation/ for some background.